# Generate multi page tiff file with individual tags for each picture using tifffile python

Tags: python, tiff

I am trying to generate a tiff file out of a couple of small 8bit images. The Tiff file is supposed to contain the images with their individual tags. (In my example all tags are the same except the description should be individual for each image)

I am getting a tiff file containing all the tags right but my images are somehow not included.
Here is the code I am using...

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tifffile as tf
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from ihb_preprocessing.settings import LOGGING_CONFIG

def getDescription(description) -> str:
    description_content: str

    with open(description, "r") as f:
        description_content = f.read()
        print(len(description_content))
    f.close()

    return description_content

def list_files(folder_path:str, type:str) -> []:

    descriptions = []

    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file.endswith(type):
            descriptions.append(os.path.join(folder_path, file))
    descriptions = sorted(descriptions)

    return descriptions


#Note that currently the only information taken from the metadata is the Size, Name from the Description and the image.


#BitsPerSample: int = 8
Compression: int = 5
PhotometricInterpretation: int = 1
#Resolution: int = [4294967295, 213274]
PlanarConfiguration: int = 1
ResolutionUnit: int = 3
Software: str = 'PerkinElmer-QPI'


folder_path = "FakeImages/"
tiff_files = [os.path.join(folder_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(folder_path) if filename.endswith(".tif")]
tiff_files = sorted(tiff_files)

image_array = np.empty((len(tiff_files),) + tf.imread(tiff_files[0]).shape, dtype=np.uint8)

print(len(image_array.shape))
descriptions = list_files("ImageDescriptions/", ".txt")
descriptions = sorted(descriptions)
descr_tag = {}
for i in range(len(image_array)):
    descr_tag[f"description{i}"] = getDescription(descriptions[i])

with tf.TiffWriter("Fake_Images_.tiff", bigtiff=True) as writer:
    for i in range(len(image_array)):
        writer.write(data= image_array[i],
                    #bitspersample = BitsPerSample ,
                    compression = Compression,
                    photometric = PhotometricInterpretation,
                   # resolution = Resolution,
                    planarconfig = PlanarConfiguration,
                    resolutionunit = ResolutionUnit,
                    software = Software,
                    description= descr_tag[f"description{i}"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `image_array` is empty!
So when you call `writer.write(data= image_array[i], ...)`, there is still nothing in it. You need to load the tiff files before in the array or somewhere else before you can write their content.